# Splitting array of dates into year and months PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of events.

```
$events = array(

array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2014-03-12',
    'endDate'=> '2014-03-12',
    'description'=> 'event description'
),
array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2013-03-12',
    'endDate'=> '2013-05-23',
    'description'=> 'event description'
)

);
```

and I need to split them into arrays by year, and then by month.

So like :

```
array(
    'year'=>'2014',
    'months'=>
        array(
            'Jan',
            'events'=>
                array(
                    'title'=>'event title',
                    'startDate'=> '2014-01-12',
                    'endDate'=> '2014-01-12',
                    'description'=> 'event description'
                ),
                array(
                    'title'=>'event title',
                    'startDate'=> '2014-03-12',
                    'endDate'=> '2014-03-12',
                    'description'=> 'event description'
                )
        )
),
```

I'm not a pro at programming and PHP so any help would be great.

Comment: what will happen if there more than one year like 2013, 2015

Comment: That's the issue, i need them to be in an array by years, and then within that an array by months, i'm building an events view that allows you to drill down into years and months.

Comment: i have an solution make year and month as index of array. wait i am providing some solution may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should produce something which you could use:

```
$ordered_events = array();

foreach ($events as $event) {
    list($startYear, $startMonth, $startDay) = split("-", $event['startDate']);
    $ordered_events[$startYear][$startMonth][$startDay][] = $event;
    if ($event['startDate'] != $event['endDate']) {
        list($endYear, $endMonth, $endDay) = split("-", $event['endDate']);
        $ordered_events[$endYear][$endMonth][$endDay][] = $event;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Array(
    [2014] => Array(
            [03] => Array(
                    [12] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [title] => event title
                                    [startDate] => 2014-03-12
                                    [endDate] => 2014-03-12
                                    [description] => event description
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [2013] => Array(
            [03] => Array(
                    [12] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [title] => event title
                                    [startDate] => 2013-03-12
                                    [endDate] => 2013-05-23
                                    [description] => event description
                                )
                        )
                )
            [05] => Array(
                    [23] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [title] => event title
                                    [startDate] => 2013-03-12
                                    [endDate] => 2013-05-23
                                    [description] => event description
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

// Updated to add endDate.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$events = array(

array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2014-01-12',
    'endDate'=> '2014-01-12',
    'description'=> 'event description'
),
array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2014-01-15',
    'endDate'=> '2014-01-16',
    'description'=> 'event description'
),
array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2014-03-9',
    'endDate'=> '2014-03-12',
    'description'=> 'event description'
),
array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2013-03-12',
    'endDate'=> '2013-03-23',
    'description'=> 'event description'
),
array(
    'title'=>'event title',
    'startDate'=> '2013-03-31',
    'endDate'=> '2013-03-23',
    'description'=> 'event description'
)


);
echo "<b>Input : </b>";
print_r($events);
$arr_output = array();
foreach($events as $key=>$arr)
{
    $date = $arr['startDate'];
    $arr_dates = explode("-", $date);
    $year = $arr_dates[0];
    $month = $arr_dates[1];

    $arr_output[$year][$month][] = $arr;
}
echo "<b>Output : </b>";
print_r($arr_output);
```

**OUTPUT ARRAY:**

```
Array
(
    [2014] => Array
        (
            [01] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => event title
                            [startDate] => 2014-01-12
                            [endDate] => 2014-01-12
                            [description] => event description
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => event title
                            [startDate] => 2014-01-15
                            [endDate] => 2014-01-16
                            [description] => event description
                        )

                )

            [03] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => event title
                            [startDate] => 2014-03-9
                            [endDate] => 2014-03-12
                            [description] => event description
                        )

                )

        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [03] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => event title
                            [startDate] => 2013-03-12
                            [endDate] => 2013-03-23
                            [description] => event description
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => event title
                            [startDate] => 2013-03-31
                            [endDate] => 2013-03-23
                            [description] => event description
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/Xh0CBYqh)**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Johan that worked, one issue i forgot to mention is that an event has a start and an end date. Which means it can span across more than one month. How would i go about sorting them into months, if the end date finishes in the next month along, it would need to show up in both months.

Appreciate all the help, you guys are life savers!

Comment: You could add the event twice. Once for the startDate (as it is now) and once for the endDate (if the startDate != endDate).

Comment: If the event start date and end date is in the same month, then it should only show up once, would i need to add an IF to the loop to check for that?